# Codeigniter Не выводит сообщение об ошибке сallbaсk функции

Tags: php, codeigniter, регистрация

Есть форма регистрации.

Первое поле - select с названием города (option value - название таблицы в бд)

Второе - номер абонента + много информации по нему. При регистрации нужно проверить наличие номера абонента в базе в зависимости от выбранного значения. Написал свою callback функцию, но она не выводит мне никаких сообщений:

http://pastebin.com/mkEGXCGD

```
//поле которое обрабатывается:
<?php echo form_error('login'); ?>
<input name="login" id="login" class="textbox">


//обработка:
$this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'логин', 'required|numeric|callback_exist_abon');


// функция в модели:
function check_abon_for_exist($str, $table)
{
    $this->db->select('1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id', $str);
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    return $query->num_rows() != 0;
}



//Функция в контроллере:
function exist_abon($str)
{
    $this->load->model('abon_model');
    $table = $_POST['city']."_abonent";
    $check = $this->abon_model->check_abon_for_exist($str, $table);
    var_dump($check); // при внесении несуществующего значения в базе возвращает false
    if($check = FALSE)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('exist_abon', 'информация по абоненту отсутствует в таблице '.$table);
            return FALSE;
        }

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! здесь принята модель: вы задаёте вопрос, вам отвечают. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, то, что вы написали, так, чтобы это было вопросом, а не только изложением возникших у вас проблем и требований. исправления можно внести, нажав [edit] ниже текста (пока ещё не) вопроса.

Comment: может ошибка тут `if($check = FALSE)` если это проверка, тогда должно быть `if($check == FALSE)`

Comment: Дополню предыдущий комментарий. Это точно ошибка. И мы никогда не попадаем в тело управляющей конструкции if(условие), т.к. всегда в условии получаем false. $check = FALSE - всегда дает false, потому что это не сравнение, а присваивание.